# Significance of 'XXX.min.js' file in Wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, wordpress, plugins

I was debugging the 'woo-variation-gallery' plugin for Wordpress.
I found that under 'asset->js' folder, for every XXX.js file there is a XXX.min.js file present.
For example :

```
1. admin.js ---- admin.min.js
2. frontend.js ----- frontend.min.js
3. so on....
```

I would like to understand the significance of xxx.min.js file ?
What's the purpose of these *.min.js files ? Why corresponding to every .js file in the folder, there is a .min.js file present ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little disappointing that you didn't [Google 'min.js'](https://www.google.com/search?q=min.js) before raising this on Stackoverflow, but perhaps you're getting started at this so welcome!

As you'll see from the first hit, a min.js file is a javascript file that has undergone [minification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)#:%7E:text=Javascript) which reduces the size and simplifies the code as much as possible without changing any of its behaviour.

This typically makes it unreadable by replacing meaningful names with ultra-short ones, substituting unconventional but performant implementations and eliminating whitespace and unnecessary separators.

A more nuanced but related question is why do they have the non-minified versions there too, given presumably only the min.js files are actually loaded and run. I guess that's for the potential of debugging the running code using a [sourcemap](https://blog.teamtreehouse.com/introduction-source-maps) where you can be actually running the minified version but stepping line-by-line through the human-friendly version.

It's always worth investing a little bit of time researching a question before raising it here. You normally learn a lot while proving you did your research, and often you find the answer yourself and don't need to raise it at all.